# Unable to run espresso test

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

When I try to run an espresso test for my app that uses data binding, I see following errors:

```
....... ........ Warning: library class android.databinding.DataBindingUtil depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.DataBindingUtil depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.DataBindingUtil depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.DataBindingUtil depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.DataBindingUtil depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.ViewDataBinding depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.ViewDataBinding depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.ViewDataBinding depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.ViewDataBinding depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.databinding.ViewDataBinding depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent Warning: library class android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner depends on program class junit.framework.TestSuite Warning: library class android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner depends on program class junit.framework.TestSuite Warning: library class android.test.TestSuiteProvider depends on program class junit.framework.TestSuite

Note: there were 6 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass) 
Note: there were 25 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').


(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)

Warning: there were 118 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.

(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) 

Warning: there were 20 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency) 

Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.  
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)

Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebugAndroidTest'.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Is there any known issue of espresso not working with apps using data binding?

If not, can you please help me with fixing above errors?